# Counting number of occurrence of each char (Elixir)?

Tags: elixir

In JS, I can do something like this:

```
function countIt(str){
  let obj = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(!obj[str[i]]){
      obj[str[i]] = 1;
    } else {
      obj[str[i]]++;
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(countIt("hello"));
//returns {
  e: 1,
  h: 1,
  l: 2,
  o: 1
}
```

What is the best way to count the occurrence of each character with `Map` in Elixir considering its immutability?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What is the general strategy for functional languages to solve this type of problem?

**[`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3)**

```rb
"Hello World"
|> String.graphemes()
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn char, acc ->
     Map.put(acc, char, (acc[char] || 0) + 1)
   end)
#⇒ %{" " => 1, "H" => 1, "W" => 1, "d" => 1,
#    "e" => 1, "l" => 3, "o" => 2, "r" => 1}
```

---

or (credits to @Dogbert) using [`Map.update/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#update/4):

```rb
"Hello World"
|> String.graphemes()
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn char, acc ->
     Map.update(acc, char, 1, &(&1 + 1))
   end)
```

---

Or, maybe more idiomatic, based on pattern matching reducer arguments to determine whether we should add or initiate the counter:

```rb
"Hello World"
|> String.graphemes()
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn char, acc ->
     case acc do
       %{^char => count} -> %{acc | char => count + 1}
       _ -> Map.put(acc, char, 1)
     end
   end)
```

Comment: @Dogbert many thanks, updated, I didn’t know about `Map.update/4`.

Comment: The additional `case` in your last example is not really necessary, you can just use pattern matching with `fn` directly.

Comment: @PatrickOscity negative. Map keys can be matched against predefined (pinned) variables only. `fn char, %{char => _}` raises `CompileError`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Interesting. Of course you're right, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 3):

With `Elixir-1.10` you can do this with Enum.frequencies function in a single line

```elixir
iex(1)> "Hello World" |> String.graphemes |> Enum.frequencies
%{
  " " => 1,
  "H" => 1,
  "W" => 1,
  "d" => 1,
  "e" => 1,
  "l" => 3,
  "o" => 2,
  "r" => 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that you can accomplish this is with a tail recursive function.  This function won't add any more frames to the stack because during run time the function will just go back to the top of itself instead making another call.  In order to accomplish this you would need to have an accumulator function like `_count`.

```
defmodule Kitten do
  def count(word) do
    word
    |> _count
  end

  defp _count("", acc), do: acc

  defp _count(<<head::utf8, tail::binary>>, acc \\ %{}) do
    updated_acc = Map.update(acc, <<head>>, 1, &(&1 + 1))
    _count(tail, updated_acc)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to count the occurrence of each character with Map in Elixir considering its immutability? What is the general strategy for functional languages to solve this type of problem?

You can use [Map.new/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) and get a cleaner code:

**count.exs**:

```erlang
defmodule Count do
  def count_it(str) do
    str
      |> Map.new( &{<<&1 :: utf8>>,
         Enum.count(str,fn x -> &1 == x end)}
      )
  end
end
```

**Test it with**: `iex count.exs`

```erlang
iex(1)> Count.count_it('hello')
%{"e" => 1, "h" => 1, "l" => 2, "o" => 1}

iex(2)>
```